# Apple app store submission requirement when submitting app that uses mailcore. (That uses crypto library)

Tags: appstore-approval, mailcore

Our IOS app has been updated to support some email features.  To do this we leveraged the mailcore framework but in doing so our app now uses encryption technologies. My question is that now that we have encryption technologies (crypto library that mailcore uses) what are the apple app store submission requirements? How do we answer the app store encryption submission questions when the use of the encryption is completely managed by a third party library?

Comment: have you submit your application ? Apple accept it ?
i'll use coreMail in one project and wont have truble.
you can see this if you have to give Apple the SNAP-R or CCATS : 

http://zetetic.net/blog/2009/08/03/mass-market-encryption-commodity-classification-for-iphone-applications-in-8-easy-steps/